# outbound connections (curl, sockets) not working for apache but working as root

Tags: apache, curl, centos, phpmailer, plesk

After a recent automatic update to linux components (CentOS v7 with PLesk 17.8.11)  my web (php) applications are no longer enabled to do outbound connections. 
Both "curl" requests and PHPMailer fail; curl is returning http code 0 with no content, while PHPMailer says "SMTP Connect() failed". 
The same statements/programs work perfectly when run from terminal (root user). In other words, if I write a trivial program executing "curl http://www.example.com" and run it from terminal, it works; if I call it from a browser, it does not work. 
The same is true for any program using PHPMailer to send a mail. 
SELinux is disabled, so it does not depends on the httpd_can_network_connect SELinux boolean.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, but I did not really understood what the real reason was. By default, my CentOS+Plesk server has SELinux disabled: I changed it to "enabled" with SELINUX=permissive, then I changed two SELinux booleans:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on
```

Even if SELinux is in warning-only mode, settings those two booleans on made the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, affected domains are using system PHP, which was updated recently. Correct me if I am wrong.

What would explain broken PHP functionality, because during the update of system PHP package, Apache restart is not triggered by Plesk.

Simply restart Apache in **Tools & Settings > Service Management** or by using `systemctl restart httpd`. If the issue still persist after that, try to switch to any of Plesk PHP versions.

Comment: Not so simple. I restarted httpd, changed the php version, and restart the server itself: no effect. I then found a solution, as described in my next post.